# Nested SQL AND OR Statement fails. Where is my mistake?

Tags: sql

I wanna get the data set where either latitude is between x and y value OR where adress is equal to xyz. But this fails:

```
... 
 Running query: 

    SELECT 
    title,description,adress,likesAmount,price,hasVideo,thumbnail,colorId, colorId2, colorId3,conditionId,materialId, materialId2, materialId3 ,verified,classic,subcategoryId,categoryId,dateUpdatedInt,brandId,userId,tblAddID,timeCreated,timeUpdated,isSold, soldToUserID            
    FROM 10299_12188_tblAdds 
    Where soldToUserID=0  
    AND (price >= null AND price <= null) AND (latitude >= 0 AND latitude <= 0) OR (adress = null) AND (longitude >= 0 AND longitude <= 0) OR (adress = null) AND (dateUpdatedInt >= null) AND (classic = null) AND (conditionId = null) AND (verified = null) AND (categoryId = null) AND (subcategoryId = null OR subcategoryId = null OR subcategoryId = null)  AND (materialId = null OR materialId2 = null OR materialId3 = null OR materialId = null OR materialId2 = null OR materialId3 = null OR materialId = null OR materialId2 = null OR materialId3 = null)  AND (brandId = null OR brandId = null OR brandId = null)  ORDER BY price ASC LIMIT null, null
```

Where is my mistake?

Thank you!

Comment: Why does it fail (error code or just doesn't work) and what db are you on?

Comment: Quite apart from you not telling us what "this fails" actually means, nor us having no means of running this code ourselves, there's also the fact that this is your code stripped of everything but parentheses - `(()))(()))` - which by my count is 4 opens and 6 closes. So either this is part of a far larger query we have to guess about or it's a basic syntax error.

Comment: excuse me, I added the whole query.

Comment: `price >= null` comparison evaluates to _unknown_, which isn't _true_. That means no rows will be returned.

Comment: However, strictly `price >= null` is a _syntax error_. (But unfortunately allowed by some databases.)

Comment: `latitude >= 0 AND latitude <= 0` is only true for `latitude = 0`

Comment: `adress = null` will never be true - use `adress IS null`

Comment: You need second-level parenthesis to enclose your first two OR clauses.

Comment: @RBarryYoung can you explain that further?

Comment: When you mix ANDs and ORs, it is difficult to see what is evaluated first. So instead of "A or B and C", use either "(A or B) and C" or "A or (B and C)", whichever it needs to be

Comment: @Jay: See eshrivana's answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you need to change this part and since now you updated your full query , maybe with other parts as well:

```
  AND (
        latitude >= 0
        AND latitude <= 0
    )
    OR (adress = null)
    AND (
        longitude >= 0
        AND longitude <= 0
    )
    OR (adress = null)
```

to this :

```
  AND (
      ((latitude >= 0  AND latitude <= 0)    
       AND (longitude >= 0 AND longitude <= 0))      
       OR (adress is null)
)
```

Comment: Thanks, you are correct.

Comment: you are welcome

Answer (score 0):

This is my attempt, I'm unsure what these statements are doing for you without more context. `(latitude >= 0 AND latitude <= 0)`, my confusion is that if the number is less than or equal to 0, as well as greater than or equal to 0, that is every number. Do you mean this to be not null?

```
    SELECT title,
    description,
    adress,
    likesAmount,
    price,
    hasVideo,
    thumbnail,
    colorId,
    colorId2,
    colorId3,
    conditionId,
    materialId,
    materialId2,
    materialId3,
    verified,
    classic,
    subcategoryId,
    categoryId,
    dateUpdatedInt,
    brandId,
    userId,
    tblAddID,
    timeCreated,
    timeUpdated,
    isSold,
    soldToUserID
FROM 10299 _12188_tblAdds
WHERE 1=1
AND soldToUserID = 0
AND PRICE IS NOT NULL
AND dateUpdatedInt IS NOT NULL
AND classic IS NULL
AND conditionId IS NULL
AND verified IS NULL
AND categoryId IS NULL
AND (
        subcategoryId IS NULL
        OR subcategoryId IS NULL
        OR subcategoryId IS NULL
        )
AND (
    materialId IS NULL
    OR materialId2 IS NULL
    OR materialId3 IS NULL
    OR materialId IS NULL
    OR materialId2 IS NULL
    OR materialId3 IS NULL
    OR materialId IS NULL
    OR materialId2 IS NULL
    OR materialId3 IS NULL
    )
    AND (
        brandId IS NULL
        OR brandId IS NULL
        OR brandId IS NULL
        )
ORDER BY price ASC LIMIT NULL,
    NULL
```

Comment: `(latitude >= 0 AND latitude <= 0)` is only true when latitude is **both** `>=0` **and** `<=0`, so only 0 is valid. An OR would contain all values. Yes, it's a strange condition

Comment: That's what I was initially thinking but it is < = meaning value less than or 0,  <=, value greater than or 0. Isn't that the entire number range? That would make sense if just (latitude > 0 AND latitude < 0) where (latitude  =0) would be more appropriate. Seems like an unnecessary statement.

Comment: *at the same time* it must be less than 0 (or equal) AND greater than zero (or equal) - the computer meaning of AND and OR differs from the English meaning

Comment: I understand now, thank you for taking the time to explain this!

Answer (score 0):

Based on what you asked here is how your WHERE clause for the latitude and address check will look like @x and @y are the numeric values:

```
AND 
(
    (latitude BETWEEN @x AND @y) 
    OR 
    (adress = 'xyz') 
)
```

The other things on your WHERE clause need to be fixed too.
The ANDs and ORs are not grouped properly.
The null checks will, for example, happen like this

`AND Price IS NOT NULL`

instead of

`AND (price >= null AND price <= null)`